# IdentityUser Classes as Direct Customer and Reseller Customer in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-identity

I am creating a web app for a service using ASP.NET core 3.0. There are two types of users of the app

1. User like Admin and Reseller (Service Provider)
2. Customers of Reseller

I have created a class Reseller with some additional info specific to reseller

```
public class Reseller : BaseEntity
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } //login account of reseller
    public virtual IList<ResellerCustomer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

This means reseller will have a login tied to this class.

Also each reseller may have many customers and their login will be created by resellers but they will not have any additional info, however I have to make sure that I should be able to find Reseller of the logged in user and also customers of logged in reseller at any time. In future there is a possibility that there will be direct customers of the service not tied to any resellers.

So I created this class too

```
public class ResellerCustomer:BaseEntity
{
    public virtual Reseller Provider { get; set; } // Please don't worry about name :)
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } //Login account of customer
}
```

I am keep the ApplicationUser class to its minimum so it serves for Reseller, Admins and Reseller Customer logins

I am unsure if I will be able to achieve what I'm trying to. I can go ahead and try this but I have a large project here and having some confidence before I get my hands dirty would be saving a lot of time .

Is this good enough? What would be the best approach.

Comment: Based on your current information and the designed models, it is generally feasible. The only question is whether the same ApplicationUser can be these two roles at the same time (`Reseller and Customers`), or each ApplicationUser can only be only one role (`Reseller or Customers`), please give us your `ApplicationUser` model for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the response. No these two application user roles will be mutually exclusive that is an ApplicationUser is either a Reseller or a Customer but not both.

Comment: If they can only be one of these roles, I suggest you better add a column to the `ApplicationUser`  table to record the current role of each login user. (I don’t know if you have set it, because you didn’t provide the `ApplicationUser` table structure). In addition, your idea is executable.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked though I am managing roles using the RoleManager and storing them in ApplicationRole POCO